# grep: --exclude-dir that contains some text in the name

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I need to use:

```
grep -rio pattern --exclude-dir=".config/dir1*" --exclude-dir=".test*"
```

in order to `grep` for that `pattern` avoiding all the folders that contain `.config/dir1` and `.test` in the name,

E.g. `.config/dir1`, `.config/dir1/dir2`, `.test` and `./other/.test` should be excluded.

What I did does not exclude those folders, could you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your command *does* exclude files in `.test/` and in `other/.test/`.

It doesn't exclude files in `.config/dir1` because `--exclude-dir` only looks at the base name of the directory, not at its full path. You would need `--exclude-dir="dir1"`, which excludes `elsewhere/dir1` as well. Note that if a directory is excluded, its subdirectories are excluded as well, so `--exclude-dir="dir1"` also excludes files in `.config/dir1/dir2`.

If grep's exclude patterns aren't sufficient for you, you can combine `find` with `grep`. The syntax of `find` is more complex, but it's more powerful. For example, you can exclude `.config/dir1` while not excluding other directories called `dir1`. (I assume that you have GNU find since you have GNU grep.)

```
find . \
     -path "./.config/dir1" -prune -o \
     -name ".test" -prune -o \
     -type f -print0 |
  xargs -0 grep -io pattern
```

Comment: Hi, any idea how to do the same in GrepWin for Win. 10? Let's say exclude any dir that has the word "not".  The help says for exact matches I should use `^(not)$`, but what about if `not` is part of the name, like `nottingham`.